# error: jquery.js is not found

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I wrote the next row in `index.html.erb`:

```
<script src="/app/assets/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
```

I added the file: `jquery.js` to the folder: `app/assets/javascripts`

but in the console, I got an error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/app/assets/javascripts/jquery.js 404 (Not Found)
```

please help.

Comment: What is the full link of your site ?

Comment: Well it is a 404, so the server can not find the file! That would mean it is looking in the wrong location. Check the relative path.

Comment: I think the full path is: localhost:3000/workers/index.html.erb

Comment: so I have to do: <script src="../assets/javascripts/jquery.js"></script> ?

Comment: is folder app inside folder workers ?

Comment: there is the html file..

Comment: where folder app in your site? Is it in the folder workers?

Comment: thank you but I found the answer.. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Please use this one

```
 <script src="assets/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

### this one is good for you

Comment: So the accepted answer means you did not put it in a folder called `javascripts`? Really??

Comment: It is a little strange , indeed . But the convention in Rails in versions >3.1 (as you probably know)is to relay on assets pipeline for serving assets . This means the files are searched on the locations , "common" for the pipeline : `app/assets/javascripts` , `vendor/assets/javascript` and others , predefined or added by you in the `application.rb` file. You might know , that the reference to the image file is just `url('img.png')` with no other prefixes .

Answer (score 3):

The problem is from where are you calling the `jquery.js` file.
I mean, it depends of where do you have your `index.html` file.

For example, if your index.html is on `/app/index.html`, try:

```
<script src="assets/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I don't understand why it has so many upvotes.

Comment: The question is about Ruby on Rails, which uses [Sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets) to manage assets. With sprockets, anything placed in one of a number of locations (`app/assets/javascripts`, `vendor/assets/javascripts`, etc.) is accessible at `assets/`. So `src="assets/javascripts/jquery.js"` will not work, regardless of whether you have an `index.html` file in `app/` (Rails doesn't work that way).

Comment: p.s. you could put it in `public/assets/javascripts/` and then your script tag would work. But that sort of defeats the whole purpose of the asset pipeline.

Comment: Got it, I dont know about rails, so I answer with my knowledge in HTML (so I think that people that upvoted my answer were on the same as me). Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the full path, just `assets/jquery.js` is enough:

```
<script src="assets/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: What are you talking about! Do you know how relative and absolute paths work?

Comment: What do you mean? Read the docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: He's somewhat right. What I think is going on is that you don't know what your talking about in regards to Ruby on Rails, which I'm assuming you're using from looking above. Take a look at this link:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

That explains how to reference files in your assets folder.

Comment: @shioyama Beat me to it :)

Comment: You originally had just `<script src="jquery.js"></script>`, should I point you to your [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14217036/revisions)?

Comment: I forgot that [Sprokets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets) puts assets under `assets/`, and quickly fixed it. But that has nothing to do with absolute/relative paths, it has to do with how rails organizes assets.

Comment: @epascarello judging from your comment to the accepted answer, it seems you don't understand at all how Rails organizes assets.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use the rails helpers on this ?

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery" %>
```

Comment: should I add it to index.html.erb?

Comment: Typically you would add it to your layout, which is at `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`. That way it appears in all your views.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the most common place to define javascript files to add is the `manifest file` : `app/assets/javasripts/application.js` . It looks like this :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Then you have your assets added application-wide .